# Signal filtering by COM AUTOSAR module

Tags: autosar

Could anyone explain in short what signal filtering feature of AUTOSAR COM module does? I can't find any concrete explanation in AUTOSAR_SWS_COM specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, AUTOSAR_SWS_Com chapter "7.2.4 Filtering" pretty much describes exactly that.

On transmission side, the filter specifies the transmission mode conditions in order to trigger a PDU to be transmitted -> think of old CAN event or event-periodic messages. "OnChange" or "OnWrite", "CyclicOnActive" ... 
On receiver side, the filter masks are used e.g. to discard certain signal/signalgroup processing within a PDU.

Answer (score 0):

Com signal filters for Transmission pdus will be used to select the Transmission mode ComTxModeTrue / ComTxModeFalse. Signal value of that particular signal filter will be evaluated based on the selected modes.

by using this feature - Application can control the PDU flow.

Filter modes

[image: 1]