# AUTOSAR COM ISignal Receive Filter Default Value for Receiving ECU

Tags: autosar

When on the receiving side of a CAN PDU, the Isignal contained within the PDU doesn't have any ComSignalFilterAlgorithm defined within ECU ARXML, then the Receiving ECU Software should assume some default value I am assuming for the ComSignalFilter Logic to be either TRUE or FALSE.
Question is what is the default value of ComSignalFilter on the receiving ECU side?
There is one related question at the link below
[Signal filtering by COM AUTOSAR module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804455/signal-filtering-by-com-autosar-module)

Relevant ARXML Diff for easier understanding is shown below
[image]

Relevant AUTOSAR Standard
[image]